# Open downloaded file by OS right after download is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to open file right after it is downloaded. I came across https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/open but I'm not sure how to implement it to a case where I have a component like this:

```
 const onStopPropagation = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent> | undefined,
  ): void | undefined => event && event.stopPropagation();

   <Button
          aria-label="Download Button"
          variant={'contained'}
          className={itemButtons}
          startIcon={<GetAppIcon />}
          onClick={onStopPropagation}
          href={getFileUrl(document.contentUrl) + '?download=true'}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          download
        >
          {t('fileSection.download')}
        </Button>
```

Is there a way to check if the file has been downloaded an after that try to open it with a program available on the OS ?

Comment: from a web app perspective, you do not have control over that.

Comment: This is a fairly language agnostic suggestion and may not suit your needs, but perhaps you could design a service that serves as a filewatcher on the client? Essentially, it would watch the files in a particular directory and if the naming convention matches your download request the operating system to open the file?